# Run a callback only if an attribute has changed in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I have the following association in my app:

```
# Page 
belongs_to :status
```

I want to run a callback anytime the `status_id` of a `page` has changed.

So, if `page.status_id` goes from 4 to 5, I want to be able to catch that.

How to do so?

Answer (score 277, accepted):

## Rails 5.1+

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :do_something, if: :will_save_change_to_status_id?

  private

  def do_something
    # ...
  end
end
```

The commit that changed ActiveRecord::Dirty is here: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/16ae3db5a5c6a08383b974ae6c96faac5b4a3c81

Here is a blog post on these changes: https://www.fastruby.io/blog/rails/upgrades/active-record-5-1-api-changes

Here is the summary I made for myself on the changes to ActiveRecord::Dirty in Rails 5.1+:

### ActiveRecord::Dirty

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Dirty.html

#### Before Saving (OPTIONAL CHANGE)

After modifying an object and before saving to the database, or within the `before_save` filter:

- `changes` should now be `changes_to_save`
- `changed?` should now be `has_changes_to_save?`
- `changed` should now be `changed_attribute_names_to_save`
- `<attribute>_change` should now be `<attribute>_change_to_be_saved`
- `<attribute>_changed?` should now be `will_save_change_to_<attribute>?`
- `<attribute>_was` should now be `<attribute>_in_database`

#### After Saving (BREAKING CHANGE)

After modifying an object and after saving to the database, or within the `after_save` filter:

- `saved_changes` (replaces `previous_changes`)
- `saved_changes?`
- `saved_change_to_<attribute>`
- `saved_change_to_<attribute>?`
- `<attribute>_before_last_save`

---

## Rails <= 5.0

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :do_something, if: :status_id_changed?

  private

  def do_something
    # ...
  end
end
```

This utilizes the fact that the `before_save` callback can conditionally execute based on the return value of a method call. The `status_id_changed?` method comes from [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html), which allows us to check if a specific attribute has changed by simply appending `_changed?` to the attribute name.

When the `do_something` method should be called is up to your needs. It could be `before_save` or `after_save` or any of [the defined ActiveRecord::Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Answer (score 17):

The `attribute_changed?` is deprecated in Rails 5.1, now just use `will_save_change_to_attribute?`.

For more information, see [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29035).

Answer (score 13):

Try this

```
after_validation :do_something, if: ->(obj){ obj.status_id.present? and obj.status_id_changed? } 

def do_something
 # your code
end
```

Reference - http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Dirty