# Ruby on Rails detect changes in attributes in update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Hi I have a Rails app in which i wanted to know if an attribute is changed which occurs within the hash
let me explain i have params for @user

```
"foo"=> {"name"=> "name1", "age"=> "15", "height"=> "120"}
```

now when i change only attribute age i want to know if the age is changed

what i tried is `@user.foo_changed?` but it will give true whenever anything changes in the foo hash but i want it to be true only when the age is changed . How can i achieve this ?

Comment: you want to check after update or before update?

Comment: @GaganGami before update

Comment: If `foo` is a JSON or hstore column then it is not possible. Rails change tracking only works on columns/attributes and does not perform any "deep" checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
if @user.foo.age == params[:user][:foo][:age]
     # not changed
else
    # changed
end
```

**OR**

```
@user.foo.age_changed?  # this will work in case foo is associated(nested) model with user and foo table has "age" field
```

Comment: your older one was only working .. this doesnt work it says undefined method age for #<Hash:0x007f9fb3e6f910>

Comment: actually in my table the foo is a column and it contains the value like this 
{"name"=> "name1", "age"=> "15", "height"=> "120"}

Comment: @user4965201: I have updated both solution, if it helps you, you can accept it

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails provide something methods to do this:

```
object.attribute_changed?
```

for example:

```
User.first.name_changed?
```

Did you tried this?

```
@user.age_changed?
```

You can find more [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)

Comment: thats giving undefined method age_changed?

Comment: what if i have another hash as bar and it also contains age the answer will conflict this but anyways its giving undefined method

Comment: @user4965201: check my answer, let me know if it work for you

Comment: For Rails 5.1+ this behaviour will_change: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314584/run-a-callback-only-if-an-attribute-has-changed-in-rails