# Method repeating after update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using  after_commit :my_method in my rails model to invoke a method. Which runs after a form is saved. In my method I update some additional attributes but the problem is that the method reruns after I update. I believe that after_commit is causing this problem, is there a way to tell it not to run after a specific update?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using rails 5.1+ you can follow [Run a callback only if an attribute has changed in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314584/run-a-callback-only-if-an-attribute-has-changed-in-rails):

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :do_something, if: :saved_change_to_status_id?

  private

  def do_something
    # ...
  end
end
```

The above callback `do_something` will only fire if the status_id has just been changed.